# How to build custom to_indexed_json method for Tire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, elasticsearch, tire

I would like to achievie something like that:

```
  def to_indexed_json
    { 
      if source.respond_to?(:app_id)
        app_id: source.app_id
      end
      id: self.id,
      content: self.content
    }.to_json
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def to_indexed_json
  result = {id: self.id, content: self.content}
  result.merge!(app_id: source.app_id) if source.respond_to?(:app_id)
  result.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = Hash.new
if source.respond_to?(:app_id)
  data['app_id']: source.app_id
end
data['id']: self.id,
data['content']: self.content
data.to_json
```